# Access Requests recipient by Default

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, email, access

I have multiple sites that I'm receiving access requests for by not sure why. I'm curious, if there is no email specified in the Access Requests Settings, who gets those by default? Would it be all of the Site Collection admins, all of the Site Owners or the Primary Administrator (As defined at the Tenant level)?

[image: Access Requests SPO]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It retrieves the Site Owner's email address via `SPWeb.Site.Owner.Email` if the access request email field is not filled in (or is the default value of 'someone@example.com').

Comment: OK,  Is that the same User(s) as in the default Owners group?

Comment: No, it is the value of https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.owner.aspx, which would generally be the Primary Site Collection Administrator when creating a new Site. The value is a single `SPUser` object.

Comment: that makes sense, ty